# echo create command, what's it doing?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, echo

I've been trying to figure out what this line does for a few hours. I have to automate the step using ansible and can't find anything on the `create` command. Any help is appreciated.

`echo -e "create /tmp/v8-install/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M`

Comment: I don't think `create` is a command. BTW, I see that `ar` is an archive utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command is copying an [ar archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) from

```
out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a
```

to

```
/tmp/v8-install/lib/libv8_libplatform.a
```

---

Here's an explanation:

- `echo -e "..."` prints on standard output the string `...`. Every `\n` is replaced with a new line.
- The `|` (pipe) operator sends the output from `echo` to `ar -M`.
- `ar` is an archive utility (similar to `tar` or `zip`). The option `-M` is used to read commands from the standard input.
- `sudo` is used to run `ar` as root.

That command is equivalent to running `sudo ar -M` and manually typing these lines:

```
create /tmp/v8-install/lib/libv8_libplatform.a
addlib out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a
save
end
```

- `create` (unsurprising) creates a new archive.
- `addlib` copies all the contents of an archive to the newly created archive.
- `save` and `end` are self-explanatory.

If you want to learn more, check out the [documentation for AR](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar-scripts.html).